# НЕ с прилагательными на -мый

Tags: частица-не, прилагательные, причастия

Пишем слитно или раздельно?
**годами не/решаемые вопросы**
Друзья. Я решила несколько изменить "проблемное" слово. **Годами не решающиеся вопросы**
Нерешаемые - в принципе их решить нельзя. Поэтому слитно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126070/discussion-on-question-by------).

Comment: *"Нерешаемые - в принципе их решить нельзя. Поэтому слитно"* Всегда слитно?

Comment: «решающиеся» — а какой это залог? Я тут запутался. Причастие образовано от «решаться», что является несовершенным видом «решиться» — стать решённым. Возвратный глагол «решиться» = «решить себя». Получается, что вопросы, которые сами себя решают или сами решаются. «Годами не решающиеся вопросы» — имеет смысл снятия с себя ответственности. Мы ничего не делаем и ждём когда вопросы решатся сами собой, а годы идут. А «годами не решаемые вопросы» — на ком-то лежит ответственность, кто-то их годами не решает.

Comment: [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F): *решающийся — **действ.** прич. наст. вр. от решаться*. Тут всё-таки немного другое значение. «Годами не решающиеся вопросы» — вопросы, которые не решаются сами собой. А «решаемый» — это страдательное причастие. «Годами не решаемые вопросы» — кто-то их годами не решает, на ком-то лежит ответственность.

Answer (score 3):

Так как вопрос (совершенно неожиданно для меня) оказался в центре всеобщего внимания, я могу предложить сначала  **краткую теорию** по теме, а потом перейти к ответу.

Теория изложена **в соответствии** с правилами Розенталя, который уделяет этой теме много внимания: § 57. Частица НЕ с прилагательными (п. 13 и п. 14) http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77

Дополнительно были использованы материалы из учебников, грамматические и орфографические справочники, в том числе Справочник Н.С. Валгиной "Орфография и пунктуация".

**НАПИСАНИЕ «НЕ» С ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫМИ И ПРИЧАСТИЯМИ НА «МЫЙ»**

**ГРАММАТИЧЕСКАЯ СПРАВКА**

Хотя слова на МЫЙ  образуются с помощью суффиксов причастий ЕМ и ИМ,  большинство из них обозначают качественный признак и  являются прилагательными;  только небольшая их часть относится к страдательным причастиям настоящего времени.

Слова на  МЫЙ являются причастиями при соблюдении двух условий:

(1) причастие образовано от переходного глагола несовершенного вида.

(2) причастие имеет зависимое слово в Т.п., обозначающее производителя или орудие действия.

**ОБЩИЙ ПРИНЦИП РЕШЕНИЯ**

Большинство слов на МЫЙ пишется с НЕ слитно. Раздельная форма написания встречается редко, при наличии следующих условий:

(1) слово должно употребляться без НЕ, что желательно проконтролировать по словарю;

(2) как прилагательное, слово может писаться с НЕ раздельно при наличии противопоставления или усиления отрицания: не видимые, а скрытые детали; никак не различимые оттенки.

(3) как причастие, слово на МЫЙ может писаться с НЕ раздельно, если оно образовано от переходного глагола несовершенного  вида и имеет при себе зависимое слово в Т.п., например: не видимые простым глазом звезды, не  посещаемые охотниками места.

**ОБОСНОВАНИЕ РЕШЕНИЯ ОРФОГРАММЫ**

Страдательные причастия настоящего времени на МЫЙ обозначают признак как действие, протекающее в **текущий момент**. Наличие зависимого слова в Т.п. со значением производителя действия подчеркивает реальный характер такого действия. Именно поэтому орфограмма решается по особым, а не по общим правилам.

Важной особенностью слов на МЫЙ является то, что многие из них **не употребляются без НЕ**, причём это не всегда удаётся определить на слух; поэтому в затруднительных случаях следует обращаться к словарю. С учетом сказанного можно предложить следующий порядок решения орфограммы:

(1) Большинство слов на МЫЙ пишутся с НЕ слитно  и не требуют проверки.

(2) При наличии противопоставления написание НЕ всегда раздельное. Этот вариант встречается редко, например: не видимый, а  только угадываемый контур.

(3) Дополнительной проверки требуют две формы: усиление отрицания и наличие зависимого слова в Т.п.:

– при усилении отрицания требуется  установить, употребляется ли слово без НЕ;

– при наличии зависимого слова в Т.п. требуется  установить, употребляется ли слово без НЕ, и проверить переходность и вид глагола.

**ПРИМЕРЫ РЕШЕНИЙ**

1. СЛИТНОЕ НАПИСАНИЕ КАК ОСНОВНАЯ ФОРМА

(1) Одиночные прилагательные на МЫЙ:  невидимые слёзы, звуки неразличимы.

(2) Наличие зависимых слов  не в Т.п.: невидимые миру слёзы, почти невидимая луна.

(3) Усиление утверждения. Зависимые слова являются наречиями степени и усиливают утверждение: абсолютно неразличимые оттенки,  совершенно независимый характер.

2. ВЫБОР ФОРМЫ НАПИСАНИЯ ПРИ НАЛИЧИИ УСИЛЕНИЯ ОТРИЦАНИЯ

(1)  Слово на МЫЙ  употребляется без НЕ, **раздельное** написание: *никому не ведомые пути, ни от кого не зависимые страны, не замечаема никем.*

(2) Слово на МЫЙ не употребляется без НЕ, **слитное** написание (проверить наличие или отсутствие  в языке слова на МЫЙ по словарю): *никем непобедимый народ,  несмолкаемые ни на минуту голоса,  ни для кого непостижимый случай.*

3. ВЫБОР ФОРМЫ НАПИСАНИЯ ПРИ НАЛИЧИИ ЗАВИСИМОГО СЛОВА В Т.П.

При наличии зависимого слова в Т.п. со значением производителя или орудия действия следует проверить: употребляется ли слово без НЕ;  вид и переходность глагола, от которого образовано слово на МЫЙ.

(1) **Слитное** написание НЕ, если прилагательное не употребляется без НЕ: *ненавидимый людьми правитель.*

(2) **Слитное** написание НЕ с прилагательными,  образованными  от глаголов совершенного вида (страдательные причастия настоящего времени образуются только от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида): *необъяснимые словами чувства, неразличимые глазом детали.*

В том числе **слитно** пишется большое количество прилагательных на МЫЙ, образованных от глаголов совершенного вида, которые не употребляются без НЕ: *непобедимый врагами народ,  невыразимое словами чувство, недостижимый людьми  идеал, несокрушимый временем  закон.*

(3) **Раздельное** написание НЕ со страдательными причастиями настоящего времени (образуются от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида): *не посещаемые охотниками места, не замечаемый людьми герой, не узнаваемый ими полководец, не различаемый глазом.*

И ОБЩИЙ ВЫВОД ДЛЯ СЛОВ НА МЫЙ:

Таким образом, всё очень просто!  Частицу НЕ со словами на МЫЙ, как правило,  пишем слитно, а проверяем только подозрительные случаи. Это усиление отрицания и наличие зависимого слова в Т.п.

**ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС**

Правильно: ***годами нерешаемые вопросы.***

Пояснение

1. ***Нерешаемый*** – требуется проверка слова, так как оно образовано от переходного глагола несовершенного вида ***решать***; кроме того, оно имеет зависимое слово **в форме Т.п.**
2. Зависимое слово должно иметь значение **производителя или орудия действия**, только тогда «нерешаемый»  является причастием, например:  *годами не решаемые **администрацией** вопросы.*
3. А вот слово ***годами***  не обозначает производителя действия (года не могут решать вопросы).  Кроме того, это вовсе не существительное, а **наречие** со значением «в течение многих лет». Соответственно, «годами» никакого отношения к производителю действия не имеет.
4. Вывод:  ***Нерешаемый*** – это прилагательное, так как отсутствует зависимое слово в Т.п. со значением производителя действия. Есть ли у него здесь **качественное значение?** Скорее можно говорить о **переносном** значении: брошенные, оставленные без внимания вопросы.
5. О наречиях ***годами, временами***. О подобных словах говорит Розенталь в общей теме, связанной с причастиями: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80

Пункт 5. Если причастие употребляется в значении прилагательного, то и при наличии пояснительных слов частица НЕ пишется с причастием слитно: ***веками** нетронутая земля* (в значении прилагательного), *рябина, не тронутая осенними заморозками* (причастный оборот).

6. А вот пример из комментария: ***неделю не решаемый вопрос***.  Вроде бы действительно причастие. Как же так! Неужели Розенталь ошибся и дал нам неверное правило?

Но здесь описана **конкретная ситуация,** а производитель действия  **окружающим** известен, он подразумевается: неделю не решаемый  (нашей администрацией) вопрос.

Соответственно, будем считать предложение **ситуативно неполным**, вот и все дела.

Так что предлагаю **НЕ КОРРЕКТИРОВАТЬ РОЗЕНТАЛЯ ПО СВОЕМУ УСМОТРЕНИЮ**, а всему искать разумное объяснение. Давайте не будем составлять **собственных правил**, а по возможности решать наши задачи, пользуясь правилами официальными. **Анархия нам не нужна.**

Answer (score 2):

*не/решаемые* — это не прилагательное, а причастие.

Тут есть зависимое слово «годами» поэтому пишется раздельно:

*Годами не решаемые вопросы.*

Тут «годами» наречие времени, если б было наречий меры и степени, то было бы слитно:

*Совершенно нерешаемые вопросы.*

Или просто без зависимого слова:

*Накопились нерешаемые вопросы.*

Но если есть зависимое солово, тогда раздельно:

*Накопились не решаемые Петром вопросы.*

Также если есть противопоставление:

*Это не решаемые, а уже решенные вопросы.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126069/discussion-on-answer-by-eagle-----).

Answer (score 2):

**Это не ответ, а пояснение к ошибке, допущенной участником Eagle при ответе**.

[**Розенталь, п. 14.**](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77)

**Причастиями** они (слова на ***-мый***) являются, если при них в качестве пояснительного слова употребляется **творительный действующего лица, реже — творительный орудия:** ***не любимый** матерью ребёнок*; *движение, **не тормозимое** воздухом*.

При наличии **других пояснительных слов** мы имеем дело с прилагательными на ***-мый*** (они теряют значения страдательности и приобретают качественное значение): ***нелюбимые** в детстве игры* (слово *нелюбимый* указывает на постоянный признак и значит примерно то же, что *неприятный, нежелательный*)...

А это мое замечание. К пояснительным словам в форме Т.п. тоже надо относиться аккуратно, **не все** они  обозначают творительный действующего лица.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126110/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----).

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ на комментарий Alex_ander**

@Sharon *Любопытно, что мнения книжно-журнальных издателей о "годами не/решаемых" разделились (с заметным перевесом "раздельщиков"). Значение прилагательного "нерешаемый" = "неразрешимый". Возможно, это и выводит его из-под обобщения Розенталя о свойствах зависимых слов.*

1. ***Нерешаемый***  в значении «неразрешимый»?  В словаре мне не удалось найти такое значение для слова *нерешаемый*, не знаю, насколько оно нормативно.
2. Но допустим, что **на практике** оно используется. Это выводит слово из-под обобщения Розенталя? Точнее сказать, что это пользователи **самостоятельно выводят** слово за рамки правил.
3. Допустим даже, что слову будет приписано такое  значение, и что из этого следует? Тогда возникает пара:  ***не решаемый*** – причастие, ***нерешаемый*** (= неразрешимый) – прилагательное.
4. **Посмотрим на причастие.** По  правилу Розенталя (пока уж не будем его отменять)  причастия при отсутствии зависимых слов тоже пишутся **слитно**, а появление зависимых слов приводит к раздельному написанию НЕ.
5. Представим ситуацию:  **вопросы годами не решаются.**

(1) Руководство региона  не контролирует вопросы строительства.  *Вот список нерешаемых вопросов.* Слитное написание? Да, слитное.

*Вот список годами нерешаемых (заброшенных) вопросов.* Тоже слитое написание, или есть сомнения?  Но при раздельном письме у нас **«года» будут решать вопросы**, так читается предложение.

Да, этому сочетанию (*годами не решаемые вопросы*) можно и такой **диагноз** поставить: **стилистическая некорректность**. А это уже кое-что. Возможно, и Розенталь поэтому **не хочет писать**: *веками не тронутая земля*. Уж у него-то с чувством языка точно всё в порядке.

(2) Текущие проблемы контролируются администрацией в недостаточной мере.  Вот  *список неделю не решаемых (администрацией) вопросов.*  Предложение **ситуативно неполное**, производитель действия подразумевается **из контекста**.

5. **Сложная задача? Да, непростая.**

Можно сказать, что иногда пользователи  **как бы выводят слово** из-под правила (привести при этом **примеры**, сходные с вашим предложением). Но тогда это будет **авторская орфография** (а ее нужно дополнительно **обосновать**, вы к этому готовы?).

Можно обозначить проблему, но не надо отвечать так, **будто правила вообще не существует**.

Приведите формулировку **существующего** официального правила, обоснуйте причину отклонения от него, обозначьте **нормативность** вашего выбора – **таким должен быть качественный ответ**. Это моя оценка первого ответа, данного участником Eagle.

Comment: Пример из словаря: https://technical_translator_dictionary.academic.ru/133896/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. Правда, речь вроде идет о математическом термине.   Извините, что сразу не учла ваш комментарий,  за потоком иного красноречия его просто не заметила. Ваше замечание в этой дискуссии, без сомнения, самое существенное.

Comment: @Alex_ander [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9) не-ре-ша́-е-мый — такой, который невозможно решить

Comment: @Alex_ander Если бы в словаре писали все толкования причастий и отглагольных прилагательных, этот словарь по объёму походил бы на энциклопедию. В словаре есть толкования глаголов, и существуют законы словообразования русского языка, по которым можно образовать от глагола причастие или отглагольное прилагательное. Была такая реклама «Не тормози — сникерсни!». «Сникерсни» нет в словаре, но мы понимаем, что это глагол, хоть и придуманный, потому что он образован от имени собственного «Сникерс» по правилам словообразования русского языка.